# Is there a database access library for C and/or C++ with a similar interface to Perl's DBI?

Tags: c++, c, perl, odbc, dbi

I'm willing to write a subset of Perl's [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI) interface for `libodbc` (or `unixODBC`) in C++.
I believe doing so will allow me concentrate better on my goal.

BTW, I prefer avoiding to reinvent the wheel, if of course something similar is already out there.

Comment: Trying to interpret the title, I think he is looking for a Perl DBI like DB access library for C or C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NVM, no odbc interface, but it is DBI like (seeing as DBI doesn't use odbc except in DBD::ODBC)

libdbi - http://libdbi.sourceforge.net/

> libdbi implements a
>   database-independent abstraction layer
>   in C, similar to the DBI/DBD layer in
>   Perl. Writing one generic set of code,
>   programmers can leverage the power of
>   multiple databases and multiple
>   simultaneous database connections by
>   using this framework.
>
> In order to utilize the libdbi
>   framework, you need to install drivers
>   for a particular type of database. The
>   drivers officially supported by libdbi
>   are split off into the libdbi-drivers
>   project. The current version of libdbi
>   (0.8.3) is supposed to work with any
>   0.8.x release of libdbi-drivers. Currently the following database
>   engines are supported:
>
> ```
> * Firebird/Interbase
> * FreeTDS (provides access to MS SQL Server and Sybase)
> * MySQL
> * PostgreSQL
> * SQLite/SQLite3
> ```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for.

The core API syntax reminds me of Sybase Open Client library!

BTW, the dbixx C++ wrapper looks very high level and clear, I can see the reason why CppCMS choosed it ;) 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a DB API that looks like DBI. Go for it - but add it to the libodbc project as a wrapper API rather than start a brand new project.

good luck.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm intending to do :)
Thanks.